# Converter notação cientifica em decimal

Tags: javascript

Como eu posso converter um número em notação cientifica como 2.6274846602703e-6 em um número decimal usando somente javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer a conversão com a função `Number()` que servirá para qualquer expoente *dentro dos limites definidos em `Number()`*. Veja:

```js
var notacao_cientifica = 2.6274846602703e-6;
var string_notacao_cientifica = "2.6274846602703e-6";

var convertido_1 = Number( notacao_cientifica );
console.log( convertido_1 );

var convertido_2 = Number( string_notacao_cientifica );
console.log( convertido_2 )
```

Uma **resposta** mais **completa**, válida para qualquer valor de expoente, é a que se segue comentada mais abaixo. Mas note que o resultado sai como **string** e, para fazer operações matemáticas básicas, será necessário converter a string para número. E, ao fazê-lo, se ultrapassar o limite máximo definido para números fracionários definidos para a linguagem, haverá aproximação do valor e até mesmo truncagem.

Para realizar tais operações matemáticas básicas em números maiores que ^19 e menores que ^-5 sem que se perca precisão, seria necessário defini-las manualmente. Não é algo fácil de processar com JavaScript, fugindo ao escopo da linguagem e da própria pergunta. Recomendo tentar só para aprendizado.

Para simplesmente mostrar como string, não há problemas. Funciona perfeitamente.

```js
// Glossário
//
// NNC = Número em Notação Científica
// NCE = notação científica de mantissa E
// BASE = obtido de base()
// expoente() = obtém o expoente do número em NCE
// base() = obtém a base do número em NCE
// inteiro() = obtém parte não fracionária da base
// fracao = obtém parte fracionária da base (em números decimais)
// N = número em NCE

// Valores de exemplo
var a = "2.6274846602703e21";
var b = "2.6274846602703e-7";

// Funções de auxílio
var expoente = function(NNC) {
  return (/[e][-0-9]+$/g.exec(NNC)).toString().slice(1);
};
var base = function(NNC) {
  return (/^\d\.\d+/g.exec(NNC)).toString();
};
var inteiro = function(BASE) {
  return base(BASE).slice(0, 1);
};
var fracao = function(BASE) {
  return base(BASE).slice(2);
};

// Converte números em notação científica de mantissa "E" (E = 10) em forma decimal
var conversor_de_nce = function(N) {

  // Declaração de variáveis
  var delta, R;

  // Obtém dados necessários
  var e = Number(expoente(N));
  var b = base(N);
  var i = inteiro(b);
  var f = fracao(b);

  // Caso de expoentes positivos
  if (e >= 0) {

    // Diferença de dígitos entre a parte fracionária e o valor do expoente
    delta = f.length - e;

    return delta > 0 ? i + f.slice(0, e) + "." + f.slice(e) : i + f + "0".repeat(Math.abs(delta));

    // Caso de expoentes negativos
  } else {
    return "0." + "0".repeat(Math.abs(e) - i.length) + i + f;
  }

};


// Exemplos
console.log("número: \t\t" + a);
console.log("conversor_de_nce: \t" + conversor_de_nce(a));

console.log("---");

console.log("número: \t\t" + b);
console.log("conversor_de_nce: \t" + conversor_de_nce(b));
```

Comment: Discordo, suponha que o número seja: "2.6274846602703e-20"
O que irá ser retornardo: "2.6274846602703e-20"

Comment: @MarceloJunior De fato, erro crasso o meu. Devo alterar com uma resposta mais apropriada e deixar explícito que seja qualquer expoente dentro do máximo permitido.

Answer (score 2):

Para expoentes não muito pequenos ou muito grandes, uma simples atribuição de valor já resolve o seu problema

```
let num = 2.6274846602703e-6
console.log(num)
/* 0.0000026274846602703 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar o sinal `+` na frente de sua string para obter um número.

```js
console.log(+2.6274846602703e-6);
console.log(+"2.6274846602703e-6");
```